# Target Bundle with hook_element_info_alter

Tags: hooks

Using the following hook you can alter form elements

```
function EXAMPLE_element_info_alter(&$type){
  // Increase the default weight range
  if (isset($type['weight']['#delta'])) {
    $type['weight']['#delta'] = 120;
  }   
}
```

How can I target a bundle  with this hook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bundles are defined in [`hook_entity_info()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_info/7), so the complementary alter hook is [`hook_entity_info_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_info_alter/7)

> Alter the entity info.
>
> Modules may implement this hook to alter the information that defines an entity. All properties that are available in hook_entity_info() can be altered here.

`hook_element_info_alter()` is for altering form elements (which a bundle is not), so it can't be used in that context.